# How to create Site quick tour of the page's new features? (like one youtube has tooday)

Tags: javascript, html

So I want when user cliks on a buttom UI to be blocked and tour started... Are there any librarys for that?

Comment: I suggest you make your question, or just use onload and cookies to make a frame appear over the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are many libraries that will do this. One I've used with success is [Complete UI Spotlight](http://nitobi.com/products/spotlight/)

(disclaimer: I work for Nitobi, who develop Complete UI)